# Find average of two lever array objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, average, reduce

I am finding average of unlocked items using the two level array using for loop. I just wanna know Is it better way of doing this in ES6?

```
let pct_completed = 0;
let total_units_of_module = 0;
const topics = _.topics || [];
for(let topic of topics) {
    const units = topic.units ||[];
    total_units_of_module += units.length;
    for (let unit of units) {
        if (!unit.lock) pct_completed++;
    }
}
pct_completed = Math.floor(pct_completed / total_units_of_module * 100);
```

Can we calculate the same using `reduce` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while probably not the most performant one and not using reduce, we can at least make the code clearer:

- we want to count the units
- we want to count the unlocked units

```
const units = topics.flatMap(topic => topic.units || [])
const unlockedUnits = units.filter(u => !u.lock)
const pct_completed = units.length
  ? Math.floor(unlockedUnits.length / units.length * 100)
  : 100
```

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible* with `reduce` over the outer array, but I really wouldn't recommend it:

```
const { pct_completed, total_units_of_module } = topics.reduce((a, topic) => {
    const units = topic.units || [];
    a.total_units_of_module += units.length;
    for (let unit of units) {
        if (!unit.lock) a.pct_completed++;
    }
    return a;
}, { pct_completed: 0, total_units_of_module: 0 });
pct_completed = Math.floor(pct_completed / total_units_of_module * 100);
```

A somewhat better approach IMO would be to figure out how many unlocked units there are, and add them all at once instead of incrementing individually. `pct_completed` isn't a good variable name during iteration either, since it represents the unlock count, not the percent completed:

```
let unlockCount = 0;
let total_units_of_module = 0;
for (const topic of _.topics || []) {
    const units = topic.units || [];
    total_units_of_module += units.length;
    unlockCount += units.filter(unit => !unit.lock).length;
}
const pct_completed = Math.floor(unlockCount / total_units_of_module * 100);
```

You *could* use `.reduce` to calculate how much to add to `unlockCount`, but it looks a bit confusing, IMO it's not worth it:

```
unlockCount += units.reduce((a, unit) => a + !unit.lock, 0);
```